# jquery ajax bug

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML page:

**sample_page.html:**

```
<h1>sample html page</h1>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sample_page.js"/>
```

The `sample_page.js` is an empty JSfile.

Now try to load it using JQuery AJAX:

```
$('div').load('sample_page.html', function(){
   alert('loaded');
});
```

Now if you use Firebug to examine the request, you'll see that jQuery requests the `sample_page.html` and the page itself gets cached (http status code 304). However, it strips out the script tags from the HTML file and executes them (probably using `$.getScript`). The problem is that it appends a time-stamp to the JavaScript file so it is never cached (status 200).

For a single paged application, this means that every-time a user goes to a page, the script file is reloaded again. Is there anyway to fix this issue?

Comment: Just a note: the `<script>` tag is [not self-closing](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/script.html). Use `<script></script>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `.getScript()` does [not support the any caching options](http://jamiethompson.co.uk/web/2008/07/21/jquerygetscript-does-not-cache/). Its source code is this:

```
getScript: function( url, callback ) {
  return jQuery.get(url, null, callback, "script");
}
```

Since it is a convenience wrapper around `.get()` you could:

- either modify the global Ajax options via [`.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) before you call `.load()`. These settings would also affect `.getScript()`:

  ```
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
  ```
- or you could modify `getScript()` itself:

  ```
  $.getScript = function(url, callback){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      success: callback,
      dataType: "script",
      cache: true
    });
  };
  ```

  jQuery will not break from this modification. This code is absolutely equivalent to the original implementation for all intents and purposes, except that caching is enabled by default.

Comment: Replacing JQuery getscript function did not work. Setting the global .ajaxSetup worked. Is there anyway to get the getscript function to work as well?

Comment: @firebird Replacing the function works,see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/5dfPX/1/). But your assumption that `getScript()` would be used is wrong. Just look at the [development source of `.load()`](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js) - nowhere is `getScript()` mentioned (search for `"load: function("` to find the line). Maybe you should set a breakpoint there and use the debugger to step through the function call and find out what's actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

In your sample_page.js, create an object:

```
samplepage = {};
```

then, in your html file, check for the object prior to your ajax load:

```
if (typeof samplepage !== "object") { 
       $('div').load('sample_page.html', function(){alert('loaded'); }); 
}
```