# Javascript: Random "Object has no method" error even with jquery.getScript()

Tags: javascript, jquery, playframework

I've been working with JavaScript and i need to call a function from another .js file.

The code works most of the time, but sometimes it gives me the error "Object has no method odometer". I've even put the code inside a call to getScript() to make sure it's loaded before it tries to call the `odometer()` function, but I'm still getting random errors.

Heres the code:

```
var updateDisplay = function(){
    console.log("refreshing Odometers");
    $.getScript("/odometer.js", function(){
        $.getJSON(
            '/getData',
            {
                product: '',
                unit: unitSelection(),
                period: salesPeriod(),
                reportBegin: $("#datepickerfrom").val(),
                reportEnd: $("#datepickerto").val()
            },
            function(data){
                    $(".odometer").odometer({
                        odometerData:data
                    });
            });
    });
};
```

I am getting an error on this line:

```
$(".odometer").odometer({
    odometerData:data
});
```

It says "object has no method odometer".

I am using the Play framework for development and I've already imported jQuery and my other JavaScript files in the HTML page.

Here's my JS import order:

1. jquery
2. odometer.js (even i use getScript, i've put it there just to make sure)
3. main.js (which the given code resides in..)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for helping....

Comment: You should tell us where you get the "Object has no method" error. (Which line of code)

Comment: sorry i missed that. i am getting error on "$(".odometer").odometer" line. which is illogical because i've already loaded that function with odometer.js.

Comment: I'm seeing a couple different odometer libraries; which are you using?

Comment: i think its a custom library, i've got that js from our design team..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like its a problem with ajax caching settings.

i've found the answer from this question:

[jquery ajax bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538139/jquery-ajax-bug)

after adding

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
```

the getScript works fine. thanks for spnding your time guys :)

Comment: Also i've learned that, modern browsers can get 6 remote files at once (including css and js files). so combining js files into one file could be another solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think

`$(".odometer").odometer({...})`

is called before odometer extends to jQuery, flow may be like this

```
$(".odometer").odometer({...});     // first called
$.fn.odometer = function(){...};    // later it was extended to jQuery
```

Comment: No, it is not. The loaded script will be executed before the sucess function

Comment: i've seen posts about firebird browser may have some issues with getScript function like running the success function before fetching the script. but its also happening in chrome browser too.

Comment: i guess i've found the answer, i'will tell you when i try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538139/jquery-ajax-bug